# "No wifi adapter found" on Thinkbook 13s

Tags: networking, lenovo, 22.10

I set up a dual boot about a week ago on a new Lenovo Thinkbook 13s Gen4. Ubuntu 22.10 with 6.1 kernel (keyboard/touchpad weren't working properly with older kernels). Things were working ok except for frequent crashes when waking up from sleep. After some of these crashes, the wifi adapter would disappear, but booting into windows it would be there and then booting back into Ubuntu it would be restored too. Now it is undetected in both OS. Windows is running with a local account and has never connected to wifi, but available networks had been showing up before. I have tried downloading and reinstalling the driver for the network card (according to Lenovo it's Realtek, but it is not showing anywhere that I can see). Not showing up in lspci, ip link only shows lo. Was also unable to see it booting off an Ubuntu live USB.

Comment: Linux will never touch the windows partition. If windows - with its proprietary drivers - will not find your wifi, check if wifi is turned off. Other than that is should be a hardware failure

Comment: Have you toggled the keyboard shortcut that enables/disables WiFi to see if that resolves the issue? I believe its [Fn]+[F5] on your model 

Comment: I've tried toggling airplane mode on the keyboard (F8 on this comp) but that didn't work. I'm beginning to suspect that my computer shipped with a faulty network card since it has since started working again, but still sporadically.